# Ordered results with apply_async

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, apply, python-multiprocessing

I have read that the function `apply_async` doesn't give ordered results. If I have repeated calls to a function which prints the squares of a list of numbers, I can see from the display that the list is not ordered.

However when the function returns the number instead of printing it and I use `.get()` to get the values, then I see that the results are ordered.

I have a few questions --

1. Why are the results from `.get()` ordered?
2. If I have a loop which as a variable named `a` and its value is different for different iterations. Will using `apply_async` cause overwrites of the values of `a` as it runs the processes in parallel and asynchronously?
3. Will I be able to save computational time if I run `apply` instead of `apply_async`? My code shows that `apply` is slower than the for loop. Why is that so?
4. Can we use a function declared within the `___main___` function with `apply_async`?

Here is a small working example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    print('For loop')
    t1f = time.time()
    for ii in range(20):
        f(ii)
    t2f = time.time()    
    print('Time taken for For loop = ', t2f-t1f,' seconds')
    
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    print('Apply async loop')
    t1a = time.time()
    results = [pool.apply_async(f, args = (j,)) for j in range(20)]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    t2a = time.time()    
    print('Time taken for pool = ', t2a-t1a,' seconds')
    print([results[hh].get() for hh in range(len(results))])
```

This results as:

> For loop Time taken for For loop =  5.9604644775390625e-06  seconds
>
> Apply async loop Time taken for pool =  0.10188460350036621  seconds
>
> [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225,
> 256, 289, 324, 361]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why are the results from `.get()` ordered?

because the `results` list is ordered.

> 2. If I have a loop which as a variable named `a` and its value is different for different iterations. Will using `apply_async` cause
>      overwrites of the values of `a` as it runs the processes in parallel
>      and asynchronously?

generally no, but I can't tell without seeing the code.

> 3. Will I be able to save computational time if I run `apply` instead of `apply_async`? My code shows that `apply` is slower than the for
>      loop. Why is that so?

no, `apply` blocks on each call, there is no parallelism. `apply` is slower because of multiprocessing overhead.

> 4. Can we use a function declared within the `___main___` function with `apply_async`?

yes for *nix, no for windows, because there is no `fork()`.

your time measurement of `.apply_async` is wrong, you should take `t2a` after `result.get`, and don't assume the result is finished in order:

```
while not all(r.ready() for r in results):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

btw, your work function runs too fast to finish, do more computation to do a true benchmark.

Comment: Thanks a lot George. Your answer helps a lot.

So, it would be a good practice for me to use the `.wait()` function after `apply_async` and then `.get()` the results. Then I need not worry about the ordering?

Comment: @ShihabKhan in that case, why not use pool.map?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was getting confused in the functions. I got a good [link](http://blog.shenwei.me/python-multiprocessing-pool-difference-between-map-apply-map_async-apply_async/) that explains the differences between them.